# JavaFX 2. Loading external CSV into a TableView

Tags: csv, tableview, javafx

Im pretty new to Java and Im searching the Internet for a simple way to load an external csv into JavaFX TableView. 
I was able to parse the CSV into an array but I dont know how I have to handle it now. Then I was playing with the DataFX library. But again wasnt able to pass the parsed csv into my table.
I think I dont really understand ObservableLists here which I believe is kind of necessary? Do you know a good tutorial or could you explain what the next steps would be after parsing the file?
thx

Edit: That's what I did

```
import javafx.application.Application;  
import javafx.scene.SceneBuilder;  
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;  
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  
import org.javafxdata.datasources.reader.FileSource;  
import org.javafxdata.datasources.provider.CSVDataSource; 

public class CSVTableSample extends Application {  
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
  @Override  
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {  
       stage.setTitle("Test App");  
       // Just loading the file...  
       FileSource fs = new FileSource("test.csv");  
       // Now creating my datasource 
       CSVDataSource dataSource = new CSVDataSource(  
                 fs, "order-id", "order-item-id");  
       @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")  
       TableView table1 = new TableView();  
       TableColumn<?, ?> orderCol = dataSource.getNamedColumn("order-id");  
       TableColumn<?, ?> itemCol = dataSource.getNamedColumn("order-item-id");    
       table1.getColumns().addAll(orderCol, itemCol);  
       table1.setItems(dataSource);  
       stage.setScene(SceneBuilder.create().root(table1).build());  
       stage.show();  
  }  
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
       Application.launch(args);  
  }  
}
```

eclipse says for table1.setItems(dataSource);

The method setItems(ObservableList) in the type TableView is not applicable for the arguments (CSVDataSource)

Comment: COuld you show us what you have tried?

Comment: check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332212/javafx-tableview-dynamic-column-and-data-values/13335161#13335161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [sample solution here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10729570) for a tab delimited file.
A csv file could handled similarly.

The sample works by declaring the type of the the `TableView` as `TableView<ObservableList<StringProperty>>` such that each row in the `TableView` is an `ObservableList` of string properties where each property represents a field in the csv file.  The `TableView`'s `items` list is a list of such lists.  `cellValueFactory`s set for each column extract the correct cell value for that column from the `ObservableList<StringProperty>` backing that cell's row.

Answer (score 1):

> The method setItems(ObservableList) in the type TableView is not
>   applicable for the arguments (CSVDataSource)

change your line

```
table1.setItems(dataSource);
```

to

```
table1.setItems(dataSource.getData());
```

Example Code Using DataFX :

```
DataSourceReader dsr1 = new FileSource("your csv file path");
String[] columnsArray // create array of column names you want to display 
CSVDataSource ds1 = new CSVDataSource(dsr1,columnsArray);
TableView tableView = new TableView();
tableView.setItems(ds1.getData());
tableView.getColumns().addAll(ds1.getColumns());
```

if you want to do it in standard javafx way  : [Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332212/javafx-tableview-dynamic-column-and-data-values/13335161#13335161)

Comment: Is this still a class within datafx??

Comment: @JasonWeh i don't know , i am not developing with javafx these days, please feel to edit it with latest code :)

Comment: Judging by my compile errors and quick search no longer there