# Updating TableView using a CSV

Tags: java, javafx-2, scenebuilder

Much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332212/javafx-tableview-dynamic-column-and-data-values), I am trying to update a `TableView` in `JavaFX`.  I have adopted the solution using `DataFX`.

My code :

```java
File file = new File(path);
if(file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
    DataSourceReader dsr1 = new FileSource(file);
    String[] columnsArray = {"firstName", "lastName"}; 
    CSVDataSource ds1 = new CSVDataSource(dsr1, columnsArray);
    System.out.println("CSV : " + ds1.getData().size());  // outputs 0

    //Below is commented out since I don't have data : source of the error
    //tblAthleteList.setItems(ds1.getData());
    //tblAthleteList.getColumns().addAll(ds1.getColumns());
}
```

Here is a view of my test `.csv` file :

```
firstName, lastName
first, last
test, tester
```

**I am using `JavaFX 2`, `DataFX 1.0` and building in `e(fx)clipse`**

#### Edit

Have changed the code a bit to use the `FileSource(File f)` constructor to see if this changes anything.  Turns out I am trying to print something from the CSVDataSource and I always get a `NullPointerException`.  Therefore assumming that the `CSVDataSource` doesn't get any data.  From examples I can find this is being done correctly.  I can read the file using a simple `BufferedReader` and a loop.

#### Edit 2

Edited the question... I am now specifying that the error is in the fact that no data gets pulled into the `CSVDataSource` from the `.csv` file.  The line `ds1.getData().size()` returns `0`.  Posted a very simple `.csv` file I am using.  `EOL` consists of `CR` + `LF` and edited in `Notepad++` (no `Excel` superfluous characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure column names in `columnsArray` are exactly equal to column names in CSV file (case sensitive).

i got the similar exception  when i put my column name as `year` in code but in my csv file its `Year`.

**Update According to Edit in Question :**

remove space between `,` and `lastName` in file  or put `" lastName"` as column name in code :)

Comment: I did check this.  I have modified the question slightly to show this.  The original problem was clearly coming from the fact that data was not being loaded into the `CSVDataSource`.

Comment: You good sir are an outstanding citizen!  Now if you would excuse me I will go bang my head on a cement wall for a little while.