# JavaFX TableView filing with values

Tags: java, javafx

i got a problem with filling a tableview with values. I tried the solution of [JavaFX TableView dynamic column and data values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332212/javafx-tableview-dynamic-column-and-data-values)
but this didnt work for me. Here is the code. If anybody knows how to solve this problem this would be really nice.

```
public class CSVTableViewer extends Application {

private String allColumns;
private FileSource fileSource;
BufferedReader in;
private String zeile;
private String reihe;
private String[]rowsArray;   
private String a="";
private String result2;

ArrayList<String> c=new ArrayList<String>();
List<List<String>> data;

/**
 * @return the zeile
 */
public String getZeile() {
    return zeile;
}



 public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException  { 
  TableView tableView = new TableView();
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[;\\/|\\t]" );
  Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[\\s\\s]");
  //DataSourceReader dsr1 = new FileSource("your csv file path");
  String input = Dialogs.showInputDialog(stage, "Please enter path to csv:", "Input  
  Dialog", "Input Path");
  try{
   this.fileSource = new FileSource(input);     
   in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
   allColumns=in.readLine();
   }catch(IOException e){
      Dialogs.showErrorDialog(stage, "No CSV-File Found");
      System.exit(0);
  }


 // Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[;\\.,/|.\\t]" );
  String[] columnsArray=p.split(allColumns);// create array of column names you want to   
  display
  for(int i=0;i<columnsArray.length;i++){
 //  a.add(columnsArray[i]);

    }

  CSVDataSource ds1 = new CSVDataSource(this.fileSource,columnsArray);
  //TableView tableView = new TableView();
 // tableView.setItems(ds1.getData());
  tableView.getColumns().addAll(ds1.getColumns());
  tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);





  try {
       while ((reihe = in.readLine()) != null) {

           String[]row=p.split(reihe);


          // System.out.println(als);


      for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
          String result=row[i].toString();
          c.add(result);

        }}




        }catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(CSVTableViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);



      }

       /* 
     ObservableList<ObservableList> csvData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 

     for(List<String> dataList : data) {
     ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      for( String rowData : dataList) {
      row.add(rowData);
       }
      / add each row to cvsData
     }

    tableView.setItems(csvData);
    */
    /* Fills 'columns' and 'data' */





 // zeile=in.readLine();
 // System.out.println(zeile);
 // rowsArray=p.split(zeile);





  //TableView tableView = new TableView();
  // tableView.setItems(musics);

  //ObservableList musics = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  //musics.add(a);
  //CSVDataSource ds2 = new CSVDataSource(fileSource,rowsArray);
  //TableView tableView = new TableView();
  //tableView.setItems(ds2.g);



 //  } catch (IOException ex) {
   //    Logger.getLogger(CSVTableViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  // }

  //tableView.getColumns().addAll(ds2.getData());


  //CSVDataSource ds2 = new CSVDataSource(fileSource,rowsArray);
  //TableView tableView = new TableView();
  // tableView.setItems(musics);
  //tableView.getColumns().addAll(ds1.getColumns());


  // ObservableList musics = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  //musics.add(a);
  // tableView.setItems(musics);
  ObservableList<ObservableList> csvData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 


  ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  for( String rowData : c) {
    row.add(rowData); 

   // add each row to cvsData
    }
   csvData.add(row);
    tableView.setItems(csvData);

     /*
   for(List<String> dataList : data) {
      ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
      ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      for( String rowData : c) {
          row.add(rowData);

      }
      tableView.setItems(row);

     stage.setScene(SceneBuilder.create().root(tableView).build());  
     stage.show();

   // stage.setScene(SceneBuilder.create().root(tableView).build());  





    // stage.show();  

    /*
      stage.setTitle("Test App");  
     // Just loading the file...  
       FileSource fs = new FileSource("artikel_demo.csv");    
    // Now creating my datasource 
     CSVDataSource dataSource = new CSVDataSource(  
             fs, "order-id", "order-item-id");  
     @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")  
     TableView table1 = new TableView();  
     TableColumn<?, ?> orderCol = dataSource.getNamedColumn("order-id");  
   TableColumn<?, ?> itemCol = dataSource.getNamedColumn("order-item-id");    
   table1.getColumns().addAll(orderCol, itemCol);  
   table1.setItems(dataSource.getData()); 
   stage.setScene(SceneBuilder.create().root(table1).build());  
   stage.show();  

  */
   //stage.setScene(SceneBuilder.create().root(tableView).build());  
   //stage.show(); 


  //  scene.getRoot().getChildren();

   stage.setScene(SceneBuilder.create().root(tableView).build());  
   stage.show();
       }




/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Application.launch(args); 
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

in yourCarryObject class:

```
public ObservableList<String> getData() {
    ObservableList<String> ostr = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    ostr.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
      String result=row[i].toString(); // if you are importing data from that row array
      ostr.add(result);
    }
    return ostr;
}
```

and later

```
table.setItems(yourCarryObject.getData());
```

Comment: What exactly is a CarryObject class??

Comment: It is a class which one instance (object) of that class carries your data. 

You can write methods by your needs in that class like: add more data, remove data, read from file, etc. 

The getData() method then "prepares" data for filling the table by transforming that data into ObservableList which table accepts.

Sorry for late answear.
If you want, I can send you my full code of some kind of adress book which I made few mounths ago, where I used this logic.